# What's the best way to compile a list of all Parent objects of a list of child objects?

Tags: c#, linq, generic-collections

Suppose I have a child and parent class like this:

```
public Parent
{
    public ID {get; set;}
    public Name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

public Child
{
    public ID {get; set;}
    public Name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Parent> Parents {get; set;}
}
```

What is the best way (using linq or otherwise) to compile a list of all the Parents or all the Children of a `ICollection<Child>` or a `List<Child>`?

Comment: @AntP I believe the OP wants has a `List<Child>` and wants to get all the parents of all of the `Child` objects on that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpeted this as a way to get all the parents of a given list of children.

`IEnumerable<Parent> parents = childList.SelectMany(c => c.Parents).Distinct();`

Comment: I suggest to add `Distinct()` not to repeat same parent entries in brothers and sisters

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
from p in Parents
where p.Children.Any(Function(x) ChildList.Contains(x))
```